# Enemy doesn't follow player (pygame)

Tags: python, pygame

So I followed the answers in another question asked on StackOverflow but it seems that I have missed something. I went ahead after reading the answer and copied the code and adjusted it to my variables and class names.

The following is the error code that Idle gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programme (x86)\Python\Games\Zombie Game\Zombie Game_Test1.py", line 133, in <module>
  Zombie.move_towards_Char(Char)
TypeError: move_towards_Char() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Char'
```

This is where I looked:
[How to make an enemy follow the player in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20044791/how-to-make-an-enemy-follow-the-player-in-pygame)

```
import pygame
import turtle
import time
import math
import random
import sys
import os
pygame.init()

WHITE = (255,255,255)
GREEN = (0,255,0)
RED = (255,0,0)
BLUE = (0,0,255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)

BGColor = (96,128,56)
ZColor = (225,0,0)
PColor = (0,0,255)

MOVE = 2.5

size = (1920, 1080)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Zombie Game")

class Char(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color, pos, radius, width):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([radius*2, radius*2])
        self.image.fill(WHITE)
        self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)
        pygame.draw.circle(self.image, color, [radius, radius], radius, width)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def moveRightP(self, pixels):
        self.rect.x += pixels
        pass

    def moveLeftP(self, pixels):
        self.rect.x -= pixels
        pass

    def moveUpP(self, pixels):
        self.rect.y -= pixels
        pass

    def moveDownP(self, pixels):
        self.rect.y += pixels
        pass


class Zombie(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self2, color, pos, radius, width):
        super().__init__()
        self2.image = pygame.Surface([radius*2, radius*2])
        self2.image.fill(WHITE)
        self2.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)
        pygame.draw.circle(self2.image, color, [radius, radius], radius, width)
        self2.rect = self2.image.get_rect()
        self2.rect.center = pos

    def move_towards_Char(self2, Char):
        dx, dy = self2.rect.x - Char.rect.x, self2.rect.y - Char.rect.y
        dist = math.hypot(dx, dy)
        dx, dy = dx / dist, dy / dist
        self2.rect.x += dx * self2.speed
        self2.rect.y += dy * self2.speed


    def moveRightZ(self2, pixels):
        self2.rect.x += pixels
        pass

    def moveLeftZ(self2, pixels):
        self2.rect.x -= pixels
        pass

    def moveUpZ(self2, pixels):
        self2.rect.y -= pixels
        pass

    def moveDownZ(self2, pixels):
        self2.rect.y += pixels
        pass


all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

playerChar = Char(PColor, [0, 0], 15, 0)
playerChar.rect.x = 960
playerChar.rect.y = 505

all_sprites_list.add(playerChar)

carryOn = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

zombie_list = []
zombie_rad = 15   
zombie_dist = (200, 900)
next_zombie_time = pygame.time.get_ticks() + 10000

zombie_list = []
zombie_rad = 15   
zombie_dist = (200, 900)
next_zombie_time = 10000

while carryOn:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            carryOn=False
        elif event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==pygame.K_x:
                carryOn=False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        playerChar.moveLeftP(MOVE)
    if keys[pygame.K_d]:
        playerChar.moveRightP(MOVE)
    if keys[pygame.K_w]:
        playerChar.moveUpP(MOVE)
    if keys[pygame.K_s]:
        playerChar.moveDownP(MOVE)

    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    if current_time > next_zombie_time:
        next_zombie_time = current_time + 2000

        on_screen_rect = pygame.Rect(zombie_rad, zombie_rad, size[0]-2*zombie_rad, size[1]-2*zombie_rad)
        zombie_pos = (-1, -1)
        while not on_screen_rect.collidepoint(zombie_pos):
            dist  = random.randint(*zombie_dist)
            angle = random.random() * math.pi * 2 
            p_pos = (playerChar.rect.centerx, playerChar.rect.centery)
            zombie_pos = (p_pos[0] + dist * math.sin(angle), p_pos[1] + dist * math.cos(angle))

        new_pos = (random.randrange(0, size[0]), random.randrange(0, size[1]))
        new_zombie = Zombie(RED, zombie_pos, zombie_rad, 0)
        zombie_list.append(new_zombie)

    screen.fill(BGColor)    
    screen.blit(playerChar.image,playerChar.rect)   
    for zombie in zombie_list:
        screen.blit(zombie.image,zombie.rect)      

    pygame.display.flip()    
    clock.tick(60)    
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Oh yeah sorry will do gimme a sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major issue is, that you do the zombie movement calculations with integral data types. If the movement of a zombie is 1 pixel and the movement is diagonal, then the x and y component of the movement is < 1. Using an integral data type, this may results in 0 movement, because of truncating to *`int`*. Note the members of `pygame.Rect` are integral values.

You've to switch to floating point values to solve the issue. Use [`pygame.math.Vector2`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2) to do the calculations.

Add a member `pos` of type `Vector2` to the class `Zombie` which stores the floating point position of the zombie:

```py
class Zombie(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self2, color, pos, radius, width):
        super().__init__()
        self2.image = pygame.Surface([radius*2, radius*2])
        self2.image.fill(WHITE)
        self2.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)
        pygame.draw.circle(self2.image, color, [radius, radius], radius, width)
        self2.rect = self2.image.get_rect() 
        self2.speed = 1
        self2.pos = pygame.Vector2(pos[0], pos[1])

    # [...]
```

Add a new method `draw` to the class `Zombie`, which draws (`blit`) a zombie at the position `pos`:

```py
class Zombie(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    # [...]

    def draw(self2):
        self2.rect.center = (int(round(self2.pos.x)), int(round(self2.pos.y)))
        screen.blit(self2.image, self2.rect)
```

Do the calculation of the movement of the zombie based on `Vector2`. Ensure that the distance between the player and the zombie is greater than 0 and that the zombie does not step over of the position of the player (`min(len, self2.speed)`):

```py
class Zombie(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    # [...]

    def move_towards_Char(self2, Char):
        deltaVec = pygame.Vector2(Char.rect.center) - self2.pos
        len = deltaVec.length()
        if len > 0:
            self2.pos += deltaVec/len * min(len, self2.speed)
```

Call the methods `move_towards_Char` and `draw` for each zombie, in the main loop of the application:

```py
while carryOn:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            carryOn=False
        elif event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==pygame.K_x:
                carryOn=False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        playerChar.moveLeftP(MOVE)
    if keys[pygame.K_d]:
        playerChar.moveRightP(MOVE)
    if keys[pygame.K_w]:
        playerChar.moveUpP(MOVE)
    if keys[pygame.K_s]:
        playerChar.moveDownP(MOVE)

    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    if current_time > next_zombie_time:
        next_zombie_time = current_time + 2000

        on_screen_rect = pygame.Rect(zombie_rad, zombie_rad, size[0]-2*zombie_rad, size[1]-2*zombie_rad)
        zombie_pos = (-1, -1)
        while not on_screen_rect.collidepoint(zombie_pos):
            dist  = random.randint(*zombie_dist)
            angle = random.random() * math.pi * 2 
            p_pos = (playerChar.rect.centerx, playerChar.rect.centery)
            zombie_pos = (p_pos[0] + dist * math.sin(angle), p_pos[1] + dist * math.cos(angle))

        new_pos = (random.randrange(0, size[0]), random.randrange(0, size[1]))
        new_zombie = Zombie(RED, zombie_pos, zombie_rad, 0)
        zombie_list.append(new_zombie)

    # update all the positions of the zombies
    for zombie in zombie_list:
        zombie.move_towards_Char(playerChar)

    screen.fill(BGColor)
    screen.blit(playerChar.image,playerChar.rect)

    # draw all the zombies
    for zombie in zombie_list:
        zombie.draw()

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

[image]

Comment: Where it says `if start and current_time > next_zombie_time` , what is `start` supposed to be?

Comment: @rahsut You can ignore it. It is just a state, which indicates that the zombies start to follow the player. Added  `start` for grabbing the gif. I've just removed it.

Answer (score 1):

L{Zombie.move_towards_Char} is a self method. You need to create object of Zombie class passing the required args mentioned in L{Zombie.**init**}.

Something like below:

```
zm = Zombie(color=<color>, pos=<pos>, radius=<radius>, width=<width>)
zm.move_towards_Char(Char)
```

Comment: do I  just add it in the main loop or where?
Also  it says that these: < >  are invalid  syntaxes

Comment: You need to replace this call(where ever you're using in your code) >> Zombie.move_towards_Char(Char) with the one suggested by me.

Comment: Tried checking the other link in the question. I couldn't find the complete code. Looking at your question, you should change this in the main loop.

Comment: should I insert the color of the player in that or what should I do there where these: < > are?

Comment: Yes, you need to provide the custom values for these arguments as per your use cases.

Comment: So @devender22 for color  players color for position  players position for radius players  radius and for width players width or all of those for the zombie?

Comment: I am not sure as there is no link for the problem statement in the question. From the code it looks like you need to pass these arguments for the zombie.

Comment: I also changed some major parts of the code now there are more than just 2 zombies and they steadily increase in the  amount.